# Change hotspot of mouse cursor on a web page

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

I would like to change the hotspot of a mouse pointer, which we've changed the icon using a .cur file, to be in the bottom right of the image, rather then the top left.

Pretty much like an inverted arrow cursor, the designers/boss have come up with a nice design which almost requires this.

Is it possible to change the hotspot of a mouse cursor on a web page?

Comment: bottom right? you mean like an inverted arrow cursor? something else? out of curiosity, why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: Pretty much like an inverted arrow cursor, the designers/Boss have come up with a nice design which almost requires this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested it, got it from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property):

Support for the CSS3 syntax for cursor values got added in Gecko 1.8beta3; it therefore works in Firefox 1.5. It allows specifying the coordinates of the cursor's hotspot, which will be clamped to the boundaries of the cursor image. If none are specified, the coordinates of the hotspot are read from the file itself (for CUR and XBM files) or are set to the top left corner of the image. An example of the CSS3 syntax is:

```
cursor: url(foo.png) 4 12, auto;
```

Link to [CCS3 cursor](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor)

Comment: How would you set the co-ordinates in a CUR file?

Comment: According to wikipedia it is in the headerof the ICO file: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(icon_image_file_format)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, and I'm glad - I think you'd only frustrate your users with this.

**Edit:** I was wrong - I didn't think this was possible - I still don't think you should do it though.

Comment: Not helpful, I'm assuming the op has good reasons for doing this.

Comment: If you are using a targeting cursor, you want the hotspot in the center of the crosshairs, not the upper left corner.

Answer (score -3):

You can't. And as most people here I'd tell you to not do it even if you could...

However, I could imagine something like this for very specific cases like the page of some artist, or for a game cursor, or a sort of 3D-like map with the cursor pointing down. Now if you really need a special cursor for a media oriented site, as opposed to an information site, I'd hide the cursor, with a blank cursor file and use some Javascript to attach a floating image over the cursor so it "looks like" the hot spot is someplace else.

Of course your sites usability and compatibility will go way down, but the solution above is if you really need to take the creative liberty, and your users are open minded to this sort of stuff.